# Filter a div by its child class' value

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of checkboxes which values are like tag-11, tag-12, tag-13 etc.
Inside the columns are list items which have classes like tag-11, tag-12, tag-13 etc. So what I want to do is when some checkboxes are checked then filter the col-md-4 on its list classes. Also it must be possible to check and filter multiple checkboxes. You guys can help me finish my code correctly?
The columns all must be visible on page load.

Column:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-inner item-home">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>
                <a href="#" itemprop="url">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="tags inline">
      <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
        <a href="#" class="label label-info">Cool</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
        <a href="#" class="label label-info">Nice</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
        <a href="#" class="label label-info">Check</a>
      </li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var tagClassArr = [];
  $('.col-md-4 ul li').each(function() {
      var tags = $(this).attr('class');
      tagClassArr.push(tags);
      return false; // break each loop
  });

    if($('.tag-filters :checkbox').prop('checked', false)) {
             $('.col-md-4').show();
            }

  $('.tag-filters :input:checked').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ($.inArray(val, tagClassArr)) {
            $('.col-md-4').each(function() {
             $(this).filter(this).fadeIn(100);
          });
    }
  });

  // reset checkboxes
  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
      $('.tag-filters :checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      $('col-md-4').fadeIn();
    });

}); // end jQuery
```

Checkboxes:

```html
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group tag-filters">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="tag-11"/>Hey
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="tag-12"/>Okay
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="tag-13"/>Wow
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="reset btn btn-secondary" type="btn" name="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can make an array of all the checked checkboxe values whenever one changes. Then hide everything and use `has()` to filter the ones to show

```js
var $filterChecks =$('.tag-filters :checkbox');

$filterChecks.change(function(){
  var classSelectors = $filterChecks.filter(':checked').map(function(){
     return '.' + this.value;
  }).get().join();
 
  // hide all, then show the ones that have any of the above classes
  $('.col-md-4').hide().has(classSelectors).show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group tag-filters">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="tag-11"/>Hey
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="tag-12"/>Okay
            </label>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="tag-13"/>Wow
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="reset btn btn-secondary" type="btn" name="button">Reset</button>
</form>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-inner item-home">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>
                <a href="#" itemprop="url">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="tags inline">
      <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
        <a href="#" class="label label-info">Cool</a>
      </li>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-inner item-home">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>
                <a href="#" itemprop="url">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="tags inline">
     
      <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
        <a href="#" class="label label-info">Nice</a>
      </li>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-inner item-home">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>
                <a href="#" itemprop="url">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="tags inline">
      
      <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
        <a href="#" class="label label-info">Check</a>
      </li>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want fadein/fadeOut instead of hide/show change to:

```
$('.col-md-4').each(function(){
  var $cont = $(this).stop(true,true),// for fast changes cancel existing animation
      show = $cont.has(classSelectors).length,
      fade = show ? 'fadeIn': 'fadeOut';
     $cont[fade]();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Only, now when I uncheck the boxes again everything is hidden, but i want to show it all.

Comment: I assumed that was what the reset was for